# How do I redirect stderr to stdout and vice versa

Tags: bash

I am calling a third-party binary executable from a bash script, but for some strange reason the executable writes its information messages to `stderr` and its error messages to `stdout`. (I suppose it is a bug ...)

How can I inverse this behavior when calling the executable ?

I tried

```
callExecutable  1>&2 2>&1
```

but this seems to redirect all output to `stderr` and none to `stdout`.
I will probably need an intermediate step ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can swap `stderr` and `stdout` by using another file descriptor:

```
callExecutable 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
```

Think of it like using a temp variable to swap two other variables in programming:

```
temp = x
x = y
y = temp
```

Here's a very helpful site describing some [bash one-liners](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/) in detail.

Answer (score 2):

You need *three* redirections rather than two, using another file descriptor as a "temporary variable"

```
callExecutable 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
```

This sends

- FD 3 to the *current* destination of FD 1 (stdout)
- FD 1 to the *current* destination of FD 2 (stderr)
- FD 2 to the *current* destination of FD 3 (which is now stdout, thanks to the first redirection)

Comment: That does the trick indeed. Unfortunately I can accept only one answer.

Answer (score 1):

See the outputs as belonging to boxes (streams), if you do `2>&1`, output `2` will be in the same box as output `1`, so when you do `1>&2` everything goes back to the error stream.

A workaround is to use another file descriptor. The sequence `3>&2 2>&1 1>&3` does what you asked for.